# Libreoffice Base form connected to Postgresql does not allow field replacement

Tags: postgresql, libreoffice

I have a Postgresql database - Finance, that has 2 tables - Institutions and Investment. An investment is linked to an institution name and there is a foreign key constraint that links these 2 tables (inst_name in Institutions and Investment).

I connected this database to Libreoffice Base and created a form from wizard on Investment table. I tried to replace the institution field in this form with a list box so that I can create a lookup to the institution master. However when I go to replace with field, it shows no selections possible.

Alternatively, is there any way to build a lookup in the form?

Thanks in advance

Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was an old version of Libreoffice.

After upgrading to the latest version, I was able to add a lookup field.

Comment: To help others that run across this I would suggest adding the version numbers for the LO version that did not work and the one that did. Especially as 'latest version' is going to change over time and my experience with LO Base is that what works is not stable over versions going forward.

Comment: Hi Adrian, LO version 7.3.2 worked. I had an older version (6.4).